# Is it common for native speakers to offer to do things with "Can I"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> You have a car. You have to go to the same way as Steve, who is on foot. You offer him a lift.
>   You say to him:

The exercise is from *Can/Could/Would you ... ? etc(Request, offers, permission and invitations)* unit. The correct answer is obviously **Can a give you a lift?** but I never heard people saying this.

I would use something like this

> Hey, I have to go the same place as you, so I can give you a lift if you want.

or

> Hey, I have to go the same place as you. Would you like me to give you a lift?

I'm just curious if **Can I give you a lift?** is a natural way to say this or it's grammatically correct, but not used by native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UK English, you will hear this and many similar forms all day and in many circumstances:

- **Can I give you a lift?**
- **Can I offer you a lift**
- **Can I buy you a drink?**
- **Can I ask you a question?**
- **Can I invite you to a party?**

All are polite forms of asking if the main action is permitted.

You will also hear

- **May I ...** (slightly more formal)
- **Permit me to ...** (more formal)
- **Could I ...**

And many, many more.  In general, the longer the form, the more hesitant it is, and ridiculous things are sometimes heard in films:  "I wonder if you might possibly consider letting me ask if I could offer you a lift?"

Comment: Thanks, would be interesting to hear American English natives too. In my mother tongue, it's somewhat unlogical to ask permission to do something good for a person:)

Comment: @ArtemMalchenko: Well, if you force somebody to get inside your car, it will be called **kidnapping**, even if you only have good intentions. So permission is always needed. However, to be 100% correct and formal, you should use "may" instead of "can".